# Almost no item in network config of GUI setting on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, gui, desktop-environments, system-settings

I am new to Ubuntu and I just installed a VMWare VM of Ubuntu 18.04.6. After I installed the GUI, I find there is almost nothing in the network config area of GUI setting so that I cannot config the network by GUI. I.e. the network config GUI is quite different from tutorials on the Internet like this Good network config GUI from here: [How to Configure Network Settings in Ubuntu](https://vitux.com/ubuntu-network-configuration/):

[image: Good network config GUI]

Mine looks like this:

[image: What does my config GUI look like]

I know that there are many other ways to config the network, but I prefer the GUI approach. Could anyone give me advice about how to get the config items to appear and to let me configure the network via GUI?

---

Update after applying matigo's advice:

The name from "ip link list" is "ens33".

```
yupei@ubuntu18046:~$ ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:4f:8c:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:5a:b4:b0:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

My /etc/network/interface before editing is

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

After editing, it is

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown

auto ens33
iface ens33 inet dhcp
```

After rebooting, the problem remains as before, but there is a strange icon with a question mark like below screenshot:

[image: icon with question mark]

This gives no help, the network config GUI still lacks items as before. Thanks to matigo all the same!

---

From here on, I did a little more as below depending on the comment info in the /etc/network/interface:

```
sudo apt install ifupdown
sudo ifdown ens33
sudo ifup ens33
```

The result is as below:

```
yupei@ubuntu18046:~$ sudo apt install ifupdown
[sudo] password for yupei: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ifupdown is already the newest version (0.8.17ubuntu1.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

[image: ifupdown]

The problem remains. I still need help.

---

Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, your VMware settings did not include any network adapters.

In your Virtual Machine settings, go to "Network Adapter" and ensure the device status is set to *Connected* and *Connect at Power On*. You will also want to confirm that the "Network Connection" section is properly configured for how you want the VM to access the network, as seen in this image, [shamelessly ripped from ProTechGurus](http://protechgurus.com/configure-vmware-network-connections-types/) (because I don't have a Windows machine or VMware to take screenshots of):

[image: VMware Network Settings]

If the network adapter settings are present and the network is working, then you may need to create a file in the `/etc/network` directory. Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. List your existing network interfaces:

   ```
   ip link list
   ```

   You should see some output that looks like this:

   ```
   1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
   2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 08:00:27:85:1a:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 08:00:27:fd:77:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   ```
2. Note the interface name for your network connection. It would look something like `enp0s3`.
3. Create or edit the `interfaces` file in `/etc/network`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Feel free to use any text editor. It does not need to be `vi`. You do, however, need to use `sudo`.</sup>
4. Add these lines to the file:

   ```
   auto enp0s3
   iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `enp0s3` with the proper interface name for your virtual machine.</sup>
5. Save the file (<kbd>Esc</kbd>⇢<kbd>W</kbd>⇢<kbd>Q</kbd> if you're using `vi`) and exit the text editor
6. Reboot the system

Once the VM comes back, you should have a complete Network panel to work with.

Comment: I do have Network Adapter for the VM and connected. I even can browse WWW websites by firefox in the VM and SSH to the VM via LAN from my Win10 host. But I cannot have the config item in the GUI setting.

Comment: Updated answer to include one other possible solution

Comment: Updated post after applying matigo's advice. Problem remains.